# Accessing phonegap camera inside of child browser

Tags: cordova, childbrowser

Im using [childbrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser) plugin for phone gap in my android application to view my external site. Is there a way to activate camera on a button tap on that external site ? I tried adding code bellow to my on button tap function but it doesnt work.

```
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
    function onSuccess(message) {
        alert('Success because: ' + message);
    }
```

And to run childbrowser(which works fine) I use:

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(_url, { showLocationBar: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

The ChildBrowser is not supposed to expose the native functionality.

Is there a reason why you don't load directly the content from your remote site into the PhoneGap view?

Comment: Im using googles js OAuth to login into my application, and on success it redirets me to my online application.

Comment: if your app in online why don't you load it directly the remote url using `super.loadUrl(remoteURL)` and include the cordova.js there. it will have access to the native functionality.